# How to get Awesomium's scroll offset?

Tags: c#, .net, awesomium

How can I get the current horizontal and vertical scroll offset of the Web view (showing an arbitrary website)?

I want to save the UI layout and need the offset to be able to restore the viewport position after restarting my application. I´m using `WebControl` (WPF) with the latest Awesomium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution!

Awesomium does not handle anything scroll-related. It´s done by the underlying WebKit. Therefore, I have to use JavaScript to obtain the information:

```
var xoffset = webControl.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("window.pageXOffset");
var yoffset = webControl.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("window.pageYOffset");
```

And with

```
webControl.ExecuteJavascript("window.scrollTo(x, y);");
```

I can apply a scroll offset to the view.